# How to install paid cert to Nextcloud

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud server running within a Docker container on Almalinux 8. I was using a self- signed certificate, but for various reasons (a constraint placed on me by my customer) I need to install a certificate that the customer purchased recently.

There is plenty of documentation on installing certs using certbam pretty certainot (on Ubuntu), but nothing about using other mechanisms for installation on other distros. I am pretty certain that the installation is just a matter of replacing certs already being used, but I do not know where Nextcloud keeps its certs.

There are several certs associated with the database used by Nextcloud, but I cannot find the cert that Nextcloud itself uses.

Does anyone know where that cert is? Is replaccing the cert the only way to install the paid cert into Nextcloud? Is there another procedure I can use?

Comment: Do you have apache in front of NextCloud?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem, thanks to the question asked by Romeo.

I do not use Apache, but I did design and code a reverse proxy microservice which I use with Nextcloud.

The microservice already talks HTTPS, so it was simply a matter of adapting the paid cert so that my microservice could use it. It now works to protect Nextcloud. I have removed the older cert from Nextcloud.